# Help with tense/aspect (past vs. non-past in Verb and Verbている）

Tags: grammar, tense

I'm having difficulty with this sentence:

Tense appears inconsistent to me. I need help understanding the correct use of verb forms.

> 冬休みにずっと九州に [Fill in the blank] おばあさんのうちに**いました**(past)
>
> 1. 住む
> 2. 住んだ
> 3. 住んでいる (Correct)(non-past)
> 4. 住んでいた

Based on the bold portion above, I would choose option 2 or 4 for tense consistency. But I'm wrong and I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verbs used as adjectives don't need to match the tense of the rest of the sentence, they merely need to be true (As for, say, the grandmother that currently lives in Kyushu).